# Compare RAG results?

Tags: langchain, large-language-model, retrieval-augmented-generation

I have 2 different datasets. One dataset is meant as a documentation for the customer and contains descriptions how the customer can solve issues on their own. The other dataset contains solutions where the operations team must do something.

What is the best way to compare the outputs of these two RAGs, so that I can inform the customer directly or the operations team?

I tried to build a RAG with multiple retriever. The result is a combination of both, but the result can only be one or the other.